# lightdm stopped working

Tags: greeter

`lightdm` not working anymore?

```
$ sudo lightdm --test-mode --debug
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.30.0, UID=0 PID=6123
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-autologin-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm-autologin-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.00s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.00s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Can't launch X server X -core, not found in path
[+0.00s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Can't create display server for greeter
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Failed to start seat: seat0    

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="6.1 Jólnir"
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir"
VERSION_CODENAME=jolnir
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Why do you think this? What triggered you to run this command? I might be experiencing a related issue so I'm curious, see: https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/411

Comment: What happens when you run this without sudo?

Comment: @PeterUithoven I reinstalled elementary (on my macbook) still having issues with graphics drivers. I'm using Intel drivers with Xorg and fans are running all the time. I haven't got the time to get to the bottom of that. Sorry not helpful.